# Change Django rest framework Response Class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my first question here

I want to change the default Response classe for Django rest framework,

I've found this article https://dextrop.medium.com/creating-a-custom-response-class-for-django-rest-framework-4c1a9a65561b
But it doesn't seem that DEFAULT_RESPONSE-CLASS is supported by DRF settings

Any idea ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide more info about what you want with some minimal code about what you did so far.

Comment: Please show your settings.py file. Your question already contains a typo that could be the reason `DEFAULT_RESPONSE-CLASS` should be `DEFAULT_RESPONSE_CLASS`

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RESPONSE_CLASS': 'myapp.views.CustomResponse',
}